# Convert DateTime String to UTC DateTime String

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to write a simple piece of Java code that takes a datetime string along with the format and converts it into UTC into same format. I am able to achieve this using lot of checks and try catch but not satisfied.

Is there any cleaner way in which I can handle this. Obviously the method only does something meaningful for date formats that have timezone or offset information. I want to gracefully process any inputs.

Some samples -

Format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSS
Input 2023-06-14T19:19:52.13844

Format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX
Input 2023-06-14T19:19:52.138-07:00

Format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
Input 2023-06-14T19:19:52.138Z

Format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz
Input 2023-06-14T19:19:52.138PDT

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The formats are very different… You may stay *not satisified* because this requires checks. There's a chance you can minimze the amount of checks, so… How does your code look?

Comment: Do you want to keep the input format and only convert the values to UTC? How do you know if `"2023-06-14T19:19:52.13844"` is not UTC already? It has no zone or offset…

Answer (score 0):

For your formats and inputs, the following works:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.temporal.*;
import java.time.format.*;

public class MultiPats {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String sDate = args[0];
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("" + "[yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSS]"
                    + "[yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX]" + "[yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z']");
            Object x = formatter.parse(args[0]);
            TemporalAccessor ta = formatter.parseBest(args[0], ZonedDateTime::from, OffsetDateTime::from,
                    LocalDateTime::from);
            if (ta instanceof ZonedDateTime) {
                System.out.printf("%s = ZDT = %s. In UTC: %s%n", sDate, ta.query(ZonedDateTime::from), ta.query(ZonedDateTime::from).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")));
            } else if (ta instanceof OffsetDateTime) {
                System.out.printf("%s = ODT = %s. In UTC: %n", sDate, ta.query(OffsetDateTime::from), ta.query(OffsetDateTime::from).withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
            } else if (ta instanceof LocalDateTime) {
                System.out.printf("%s = LDT = %s%n", sDate, ta.query(LocalDateTime::from));

            }

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the length of the `String`s in order to find out if you need a pattern that is not build-in / predefined. Checking that may become a real pain if you are expecting (a lot) more than your 4 examples.

However, one of your examples (`"2023-06-14T19:19:52.13844"`) defines a time of day along with a date but lacks zone and offset. You can parse it and declare it UTC time, but you cannot be sure that time actually was in UTC, exclusively judging from the values of the `String`. If you know the origin zone or offset, you would have to add it, convert to UTC and then format without zone and offset.

#### example code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // define some formatters for input parsing and output formatting
    var dtf25 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSS");
    var dtf26 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz");
    var dtf29 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx");
    
    // no conversion needed, this is already in UTC
    System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("2023-06-14T19:19:52.138Z"));
    // no conversion possible, origin zone or offset are unknown
    System.out.println(
            LocalDateTime.parse("2023-06-14T19:19:52.13844")
                         .format(dtf25)
                    );
    // parse, convert zone and print in the source format
    System.out.println(
            ZonedDateTime.parse("2023-06-14T19:19:52.138PDT", dtf26)
                         .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                         .format(dtf26)
                    );
    // parse, convert zone and print in the source format
    System.out.println(
            OffsetDateTime.parse("2023-06-14T19:19:52.138-07:00")
                          .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                          .format(dtf29)
                    );
}
```

#### output

```
2023-06-14T19:19:52.138Z
2023-06-14T19:19:52.13844
2023-06-15T02:19:52.138Z
2023-06-15T02:19:52.138+00:00
```